# startdate and endDate filter based on dates in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to add a start and end date filter. I have products that have a start date and end date. Suppose I apply a filter of the start date as 1 may to end date 30 May. In that case, those products who have a start date from 1 may are coming. But, I also have products which are used from 1 April to 30 May. These products also come because these products are used in April month also. But, due to the start date, these products are not coming.
I tried this

```
    $products->whereBetween($productUsedDate, [$startDate, $endDate]);
```

but, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: You're saying you have a **start** and an **end** date for each product, But here i only see the `$productUsedDate`, How exactly are you storing the date for each product?

Comment: should work ->whereBetween('date', [date($request->from), date($request->to)])